# Salvar no localStorage a posição para mante-la quando recarregar a página

Tags: javascript, jquery, localstorage

Quando o usuário clica em um determinado botão a posição scroll de um elemento é alterado. Gostaria que essa ação ficasse armazenada no LocalStorage, porém não sei fazer... podem me ajudar?

Aqui meu script:

```
$('.btn.parteum').click(function(){ 
      $('#textarea').animate({ scrollLeft: 0 }, 400);
      return false; 
});
$('.btn.parte2').click(function(){ 
      $('#textarea').animate({ scrollLeft: 140 }, 400);
      return false; 
});
```

exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/g43rmesL/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode adicionar um callback que será chamado ao fim da animação:

```
//recupera o valor salvo ao recarregar a pagina
if(localStorage.getItem('scrollposition')){
     $('#textarea').scrollLeft(localStorage.getItem('scrollposition'));
}

$('.btn.parteum').click(function(){ 
      $('#textarea').animate({ scrollLeft: 0 }, 400, function(){
          localStorage.setItem('scrollposition', 0);
      });
      return false; 
});
$('.btn.parte2').click(function(){ 
      $('#textarea').animate({ scrollLeft: 140 }, 400, function(){
          localStorage.setItem('scrollposition', 140);
      });
      return false; 
});
```

**Exemplo funcionando**: https://jsfiddle.net/g43rmesL/1/

> http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: obrigado pela resposta! aqui não funcionou... vc testou? ou será que eu não estou sabendo colocar lá?... coloquei exatamente como está aí.

Comment: Seu código na pergunta é insuficiente para testar. Adiciona seu html à pergunta que eu testo e tendo achar o erro.

Comment: Aqui, fiz um exemplo no fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g43rmesL/

Comment: Está salvando no localStorage normalmente

Comment: ué, aqui quando eu recarrego a página não fica na posição do scroll do botão 2, volta pro primeiro

Comment: Sua resposta não foi muito clara... Você quer que ao recarregar recupere esse valor e repita a ação né, irei editar minha resposta adicionando essa função

Comment: agora que percebi mesmo... devia ter dito que era "memorizar" e não "armazenar", vou editar

Comment: Acho talvez seria melhor dizer "Salvar no localStorage a posição para mante-la quando recarregar a página" Mas ok, está certo agora. Da uma olhada

Comment: Obrigado por tudo!!!!!

Comment: Tranquilo cara, até mais.